# Distributed Sequence ID (Long) generator in Java - Could someone validate if this design is correct?

Tags: java, multithreading

***Requirement***: A sequence ID (Long) generator which would work in a distributed environment (multiple JVMs). There will be multiple threads working on each JVM.

***Solution***: We have a centralized persistent key-value store. But we do not want to make a remote call for every incoming request, so we thought of fetching batch of sequence IDs from this centralized key-value store and keep in local JVM and  then use it.

`Key Value Store`: This is our centralized key-value store in which we keep an object `SEQUENCE_ID` with a `Long` value. This key-value store of ours has a feature of controlling concurrent updates through a version number.

`BatchRetriever`: This performs following operations:

1. Get the current value for `SEQUENCE_ID` from key-value store
2. Add the batch size to the retrieved value
3. Update the new value for `SEQUENCE_ID`

Multiple threads could be trying to do this, so all these 3 steps will be performed as a single atomic work. We use version-number feature of this key-value store to control this concurrent updates.

`SequenceHolder`: A queue based data structure which would hold the batch of sequence IDs.

`SequenceObserver`: An observer (implemented through Observer design pattern) which can check if the size of `SequenceHolder` has gone down to a threshold value, it will use `BatchRetriever` to retrieve next batch.

Appreciate if someone can validate this design and suggest a better one.

~ NN

Comment: How will the Ids be used? Must they always be used in order? Or just unique? With the current design, it is possible to use later numbers first. (Assume batches of 100, THREAD 1 gets 0-100, THREAD 2 gets 100 - 200, THREAD 2 uses ids faster than THREAD 1.)

Comment: The IDs just need to be unique; no requirement of ordering. And, yes, we do not need any id-sequencing among threads. All we care is, each thread while processing gets a "unique".

Comment: It looks reasonable to me.

Comment: Maybe easier then to: Each JVM gets assigned a unique number (in config or something) Then, each JVM generated a random number, with their assigned number pre-pended. Eliminated the centralized server, queue, observer, etc.

Comment: We use the batching approach (using async remotecalls) in our system and it works well. You need to size the batches according to your remotecall latency. Additionally we prefetch the next batch once the current batch is consumed 50%. 
Downside is, in a large cluster when you need many unique ID's and there are lots of consumers which actually do not consume them, you might run out of Ids (theorethically). If applciable hatcyl's solution ofc is the fastest and simplest.

Answer (score 5):

These are good approaches.

A simpler solution might be to use shared memory.  This has the performance of AtomicLong, while being shared across processes on the same machine.

```
import net.openhft.lang.io.DirectBytes;
import net.openhft.lang.io.MappedStore;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;

public class CounterExampleMain {
    static volatile long id;

    public static void main(String... ignored) throws IOException {
        int counters = 128;
        int repeats = 100000;

        File file = new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir") + "/counters");
        MappedStore ms = new MappedStore(file, FileChannel.MapMode.READ_WRITE, counters * 8);
        DirectBytes slice = ms.bytes();

        long start = System.nanoTime();
        for (int j = 0; j < repeats; j++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < counters; i++) {
                id = slice.addAtomicLong(i * 8, 1);
            }
        }
        long time = System.nanoTime() - start;
        System.out.printf("Took %.3f second to increment %,d counters, %,d times, last id=%,d%n",
                time / 1e9, counters, repeats, id);
        ms.free();
    }
}
```

Each time I run it on my laptop, I get

```
Took 0.252 second to increment 128 counters, 100,000 times, last id=100,000
Took 0.267 second to increment 128 counters, 100,000 times, last id=200,000
Took 0.255 second to increment 128 counters, 100,000 times, last id=300,000
```

As you can see this is really cheap, averaging ~25 ns per increment and persisted between runs of the program.  It is also thread safe and can be shared between JVMs.

BTW in a contented example where multiple threads are updating the same counters, I would expect closer to 50 ns.

The library I used was

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.openhft</groupId>
    <artifactId>lang</artifactId>
    <version>6.4.8</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Hi Peter, I am glad to see your response. I have been a big fan of your articles in Java Performance Group (Google+). Could you please help me understand where in my design I can use shared memory and point me some examples of those? Can I use any of your OpenHFT libraries to get my job done? One thing I need to guarantee is each thread must get a unique id. One of the implementation we thought of using "synchronized" methods and/or blocks. But I am little worried of this and trying to see if there is another way (than synchronized) to achieve this.

Comment: @Niranjan the problem is; you need something which is thread safe across processes.  Using a memory mapped file enables this, and makes it persisted. i.e. it will continue from where you were up to the last time you ran.

Comment: @Niranjan you can also get batches this way with `addAtomicLong(offset, n)` where n > 1 but I suspect you don't need the added complexity.